# Stream Joint Positions from a C++ file to Grasshopper in Rhino 7

Tags: c++, udp, rhino, grasshopper

I am currently developing a simulator for a Kuka robot in Grasshopper. To accomplish this, I would like to continuously send joint positions from a C++ file to Grasshopper which in turn would make the loaded Kuka robot move continuously to the incoming joint positions in the simulation. Conversely, I would also like to continuously send joint positions from Grasshopper to a C++ file.

Currently, I have successfully managed to load a Kuka robot and make it move to particular joint positions within grasshopper using the [robots](https://www.food4rhino.com/en/app/robots) plugin.

To stream joint positions from a C++ file to Grasshopper, the idea I had was to create a upd server script in C++ which would continuously send these joint positions. However, I am not sure how to go about creating a Udp client within Grasshopper itself which would continuously receive the message the server is sending.

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to work with C++ for receiving and sending UDP on the grasshopper side if you have a working UDP Server transmitting position.

If you have a UDP server set up to send messages, you can use the ‘**Fire Fly**’ plugin’s **‘UDP Listener’** component to subscribe to your server. You can use it in conjunction with the ‘**UDP Sender**’ component for two-way communications.

Here is a snip of the Fire Fly user guide for these two components.

[image]

Here is a link to download the Plugin, UDP Examples, and User Guide: [Firefly on Food4Rhino](https://www.food4rhino.com/en/app/firefly)

Here is a link to additional documentation: https://grasshopperdocs.com/addons/firefly.html

Here is a existing discussion on how to implement C++ code within grasshopper:[Mcneel Discourse Discussion](https://discourse.mcneel.com/t/ways-to-compile-c-code-for-grasshopper/102307/2)